# MVVMCross SplashScreen loop

Tags: xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am trying to create my first MVVMCross application using Visual Studio 2012 & MonoDroid. The application is targeting API level 8 & Android version 2.2. I am able to deploy the Tutorial.UI.Droid on to the emulator (changed it to be the same API level and version as above) and it seems to work. It goes past the splashscreen but when I copy the same structure and layout my application is just stuck in a boot loop with the Loading screen repeating itself. I would appreciate any help & pointers

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake and left out a view for one of the ViewModel I was using and it couldnt find it. Including that in the project solved the loading loop but it **still doesnt seem to load** the View and I need to Force Close. The emulator I am using is a galaxy tab with version 2.2

The Android device log was of a lot of help as I discovered from one of the post on stackoverflow (lost the link to that post)

http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/android_debug_log

10-17 04:10:22.574 D/AndroidRuntime(  511): 
10-17 04:10:22.574 D/AndroidRuntime(  511): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10-17 04:10:22.574 D/AndroidRuntime(  511): CheckJNI is ON
10-17 04:10:22.714 D/AndroidRuntime(  511): --- registering native functions ---
10-17 04:10:23.254 D/AndroidRuntime(  511): Shutting down VM
10-17 04:10:23.265 D/jdwp    (  511): adbd disconnected
10-17 04:10:23.275 I/AndroidRuntime(  511): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-17 04:10:23.685 D/AndroidRuntime(  519): 
10-17 04:10:23.685 D/AndroidRuntime(  519): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10-17 04:10:23.685 D/AndroidRuntime(  519): CheckJNI is ON
10-17 04:10:23.815 D/AndroidRuntime(  519): --- registering native functions ---
10-17 04:10:24.445 D/AndroidRuntime(  519): Shutting down VM
10-17 04:10:24.445 D/jdwp    (  519): adbd disconnected
10-17 04:10:24.885 D/AndroidRuntime(  527): 
10-17 04:10:24.885 D/AndroidRuntime(  527): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10-17 04:10:24.885 D/AndroidRuntime(  527): CheckJNI is ON
10-17 04:10:25.016 D/AndroidRuntime(  527): --- registering native functions ---
10-17 04:10:25.545 I/PackageManager(   60): Removing non-system package:Test.Droid
10-17 04:10:25.545 D/PackageManager(   60): Removing package Test.Droid
10-17 04:10:25.545 D/PackageManager(   60): Unregistered content provider: Test.Droid.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.**mono_init**, className = mono.MonoRuntimeProvider, isSyncable = false
10-17 04:10:25.545 D/PackageManager(   60):   Providers: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
10-17 04:10:25.545 D/PackageManager(   60):   Receivers: mono.android.Seppuku
10-17 04:10:25.545 D/PackageManager(   60):   Activities: Test.droid.views.OfficeView
10-17 04:10:25.577 I/ActivityManager(   60): Force stopping package Test.Droid uid=10045
10-17 04:10:25.926 I/ActivityManager(   60): Force stopping package Test.Droid uid=10045
10-17 04:10:26.115 D/dalvikvm(   60): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2270 objects / 139768 bytes in 186ms
10-17 04:10:26.185 D/VoiceDialerReceiver(  265): onReceive Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:Test.Droid flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.voicedialer/.VoiceDialerReceiver (has extras) }
10-17 04:10:26.185 V/RecognizerEngine(  265): deleteCachedGrammarFiles /data/data/com.android.voicedialer/files/openentries.txt
10-17 04:10:26.436 D/dalvikvm(   60): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1006 objects / 75272 bytes in 183ms
10-17 04:10:26.575 I/installd(   35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@Test.Droid-1.apk@classes.dex
10-17 04:10:26.726 D/AndroidRuntime(  527): Shutting down VM
10-17 04:10:26.726 D/jdwp    (  527): adbd disconnected
10-17 04:10:26.768 I/AndroidRuntime(  527): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-17 04:10:30.394 D/AndroidRuntime(  537): 
10-17 04:10:30.394 D/AndroidRuntime(  537): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10-17 04:10:30.394 D/AndroidRuntime(  537): CheckJNI is ON
10-17 04:10:31.224 D/dalvikvm(  314): GC_EXPLICIT freed 589 objects / 30328 bytes in 150ms
10-17 04:10:31.894 D/dalvikvm(  265): GC_EXPLICIT freed 445 objects / 20992 bytes in 64ms
10-17 04:10:32.264 D/PackageParser(   60): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl20752.tmp
10-17 04:10:32.524 D/PackageManager(   60): Scanning package Test.Droid
10-17 04:10:32.534 I/PackageManager(   60): /data/app/Test.Droid-1.apk changed; unpacking
10-17 04:10:32.556 D/PackageManager(   60): Caching shared lib lib/armeabi/libmonodroid.so
10-17 04:10:32.654 D/installd(   35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/Test.Droid-1.apk' ---
10-17 04:10:33.294 D/dalvikvm(  544): DexOpt: load 177ms, verify 178ms, opt 8ms
10-17 04:10:33.364 D/installd(   35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/Test.Droid-1.apk' (success) ---
10-17 04:10:33.364 D/PackageManager(   60): Registered content provider: Test.Droid.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.**mono_init**, className = mono.MonoRuntimeProvider, isSyncable = false
10-17 04:10:33.364 D/PackageManager(   60):   Providers: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
10-17 04:10:33.364 D/PackageManager(   60):   Receivers: mono.android.Seppuku
10-17 04:10:33.364 D/PackageManager(   60):   Activities: Test.droid.views.OfficeView
10-17 04:10:33.384 I/ActivityManager(   60): Force stopping package Test.Droid uid=10045
10-17 04:10:33.564 I/installd(   35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@Test.Droid-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@Test.Droid-1.apk@classes.dex
10-17 04:10:33.564 D/PackageManager(   60): New package installed in /data/app/Test.Droid-1.apk
10-17 04:10:34.016 D/dalvikvm(   60): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6242 objects / 413272 bytes in 201ms
10-17 04:10:34.016 D/AndroidRuntime(  537): Shutting down VM
10-17 04:10:34.016 D/jdwp    (  537): adbd disconnected
10-17 04:10:34.094 I/dalvikvm(  537): JNI: AttachCurrentThread (from ???.???)
10-17 04:10:34.094 I/AndroidRuntime(  537): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-17 04:10:34.108 D/VoiceDialerReceiver(  265): onReceive Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:Test.Droid flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.voicedialer/.VoiceDialerReceiver (has extras) }
10-17 04:10:34.114 V/RecognizerEngine(  265): deleteCachedGrammarFiles /data/data/com.android.voicedialer/files/openentries.txt
10-17 04:10:34.224 W/RecognitionManagerService(   60): no available voice recognition services found
10-17 04:10:34.894 D/AndroidRuntime(  553): 
10-17 04:10:34.894 D/AndroidRuntime(  553): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10-17 04:10:34.894 D/AndroidRuntime(  553): CheckJNI is ON
10-17 04:10:35.034 D/AndroidRuntime(  553): --- registering native functions ---
10-17 04:10:35.564 I/ActivityManager(   60): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=Test.Droid/Test.droid.views.OfficeView }
10-17 04:10:35.784 D/AndroidRuntime(  553): Shutting down VM
10-17 04:10:35.804 D/jdwp    (  553): adbd disconnected
10-17 04:10:35.894 I/ActivityManager(   60): Start proc Test.Droid for activity Test.Droid/Test.droid.views.OfficeView: pid=560 uid=10045 gids={3003, 1015}
10-17 04:10:36.204 I/WindowManager(   60): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=1
10-17 04:10:36.204 I/ActivityManager(   60): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=35 uiMode=17 seq=14}
10-17 04:10:36.474 I/ActivityThread(  560): Publishing provider Test.Droid.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.**mono_init**: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
10-17 04:10:36.504 D/dalvikvm(  560): Trying to load lib /data/data/Test.Droid/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x44f51df8
10-17 04:10:36.504 D/dalvikvm(  560): Added shared lib /data/data/Test.Droid/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x44f51df8
10-17 04:10:36.664 W/MonoDroid-Debugger(  560): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8877,server=y,embedding=1
10-17 04:10:36.684 W/MonoDroid-Debugger(  560): Accepted stdout connection: 29
10-17 04:10:37.484 E/mono    (  560): WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
10-17 04:10:37.484 E/mono    (  560): Using default runtime: v2.0.50727
10-17 04:10:40.404 W/monodroid-gc(  560): GREF GC Threshold: 1800
10-17 04:10:41.204 W/WindowManager(   60): App freeze timeout expired.
10-17 04:10:41.204 W/WindowManager(   60): Force clearing freeze: AppWindowToken{451330b0 token=HistoryRecord{450c63d0 Test.Droid/Test.droid.views.OfficeView}}
10-17 04:10:43.434 D/dalvikvm(   60): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4514 objects / 255248 bytes in 127ms
10-17 04:10:45.594 W/ActivityManager(   60): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
10-17 04:10:46.374 W/ActivityManager(   60): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{450c63d0 Test.Droid/Test.droid.views.OfficeView}
10-17 04:10:49.215 I/mvx     (  560):   1.57 Setup: Conventions start
10-17 04:11:29.324 W/ActivityManager(   60):   Force finishing activity Test.Droid/Test.droid.views.M10-17 04:10:49.765 I/mono-stdout(  560): mvx:Diagnostic:  1.57 Setup: Conventions start
10-17 04:11:29.324 W/ActivityManager(   60):   Force finishing activity Test.Droid/Test.droid.views.OfficeView
10-17 04:12:33.934 D/Pack10-17 04:11:29.324 I/ActivityManager(   60): Killing Test.Droid (pid=560): user's request
10-17 04:12:33.934 I/PackageManager(   60): Removing non-system package:Test.Droid
10-17 04:12:33.934 D/PackageManager(   60): Removing package Test.Droid
10-17 04:12:33.934 D/PackageManager(   60): Unregistered content provider: Test.Droid.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.**mono_init**, className = mono.MonoRuntimeProvider, isSyncable = false
10-17 04:12:33.934 D/PackageManager(   60):   Providers: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
10-17 04:12:33.934 D/PackageManager(   60):   Receivers: mono.android.Seppuku
10-17 04:12:33.934 D/PackageManager(   60):   Activities: Test.droid.views.OfficeView
10-17 04:12:33.967 I/ActivityManager(   60): Force stopping package Test.Droid uid=10045
10-17 04:12:34.334 I/ActivityManager(   60): Force stopping package Test.Droid uid=10045
10-17 04:12:34.534 D/dalvikvm(   60): GC_EXPLICIT freed 2008 objects / 127112 bytes in 203ms
10-17 04:12:34.604 D/VoiceDialerReceiver(  265): onReceive Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED dat=package:Test.Droid flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.voicedialer/.VoiceDialerReceiver (has extras) }
10-17 04:12:34.604 V/RecognizerEngine(  265): deleteCachedGrammarFiles /data/data/com.android.voicedialer/files/openentries.txt
10-17 04:12:34.884 D/dalvikvm(   60): GC_EXPLICIT freed 746 objects / 37312 bytes in 235ms
10-17 04:12:34.927 I/installd(   35): unlink /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@Test.Droid-1.apk@classes.dex
10-17 04:12:34.994 D/AndroidRuntime(  598): Shutting down VM
10-17 04:12:34.994 D/jdwp    (  598): adbd disconnected
10-17 04:12:38.474 D/AndroidRuntime(  608): 
10-17 04:12:38.474 D/AndroidRuntime(  608): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10-17 04:12:38.474 D/AndroidRuntime(  608): CheckJNI is ON
10-17 04:12:38.594 D/AndroidRuntime(  608): --- registering native functions ---
10-17 04:12:39.304 D/dalvikvm(  314): GC_EXPLICIT freed 184 objects / 13368 bytes in 155ms
10-17 04:12:40.164 D/dalvikvm(  265): GC_EXPLICIT freed 238 objects / 13512 bytes in 58ms
10-17 04:12:40.254 D/PackageParser(   60): Scanning package: /data/app/vmdl20754.tmp
10-17 04:12:40.504 D/PackageManager(   60): Scanning package Test.Droid
10-17 04:12:40.524 I/PackageManager(   60): /data/app/Test.Droid-1.apk changed; unpacking
10-17 04:12:40.534 D/PackageManager(   60): Caching shared lib lib/armeabi/libmonodroid.so
10-17 04:12:40.644 D/installd(   35): DexInv: --- BEGIN '/data/app/Test.Droid-1.apk' ---
10-17 04:12:41.244 D/dalvikvm(  615): DexOpt: load 174ms, verify 178ms, opt 6ms
10-17 04:12:41.304 D/installd(   35): DexInv: --- END '/data/app/Test.Droid-1.apk' (success) ---
10-17 04:12:41.304 D/PackageManager(   60): Registered content provider: Test.Droid.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.**mono_init**, className = mono.MonoRuntimeProvider, isSyncable = false
10-17 04:12:41.304 D/PackageManager(   60):   Providers: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
10-17 04:12:41.304 D/PackageManager(   60):   Receivers: mono.android.Seppuku
10-17 04:12:41.304 D/PackageManager(   60):   Activities: Test.droid.SplashScreenActivity Test.droid.views.EmployeeView Test.droid.views.OfficeView
10-17 04:12:41.324 I/ActivityManager(   60): Force stopping package Test.Droid uid=10045
10-17 04:12:41.496 I/installd(   35): move /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@Test.Droid-1.apk@classes.dex -> /data/dalvik-cache/data@app@Test.Droid-1.apk@classes.dex
10-17 04:12:41.496 D/PackageManager(   60): New package installed in /data/app/Test.Droid-1.apk
10-17 04:12:41.926 D/dalvikvm(   60): GC_EXPLICIT freed 6613 objects / 458712 bytes in 202ms
10-17 04:12:41.926 D/AndroidRuntime(  608): Shutting down VM
10-17 04:12:41.964 D/jdwp    (  608): adbd disconnected
10-17 04:12:41.994 D/VoiceDialerReceiver(  265): onReceive Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:Test.Droid flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.voicedialer/.VoiceDialerReceiver (has extras) }
10-17 04:12:41.994 V/RecognizerEngine(  265): deleteCachedGrammarFiles /data/data/com.android.voicedialer/files/openentries.txt
10-17 04:12:42.016 I/dalvikvm(  608): JNI: AttachCurrentThread (from ???.???)
10-17 04:12:42.016 I/AndroidRuntime(  608): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder Thread #3' failed
10-17 04:12:42.074 W/RecognitionManagerService(   60): no available voice recognition services found
10-17 04:12:42.934 D/AndroidRuntime(  626): 
10-17 04:12:42.934 D/AndroidRuntime(  626): >>>>>>>>>>>>>> AndroidRuntime START <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
10-17 04:12:42.934 D/AndroidRuntime(  626): CheckJNI is ON
10-17 04:12:43.064 D/AndroidRuntime(  626): --- registering native functions ---
10-17 04:12:43.614 I/ActivityManager(   60): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN flg=0x10000000 cmp=Test.Droid/Test.droid.SplashScreenActivity }
10-17 04:12:43.824 D/AndroidRuntime(  626): Shutting down VM
10-17 04:12:43.854 D/jdwp    (  626): adbd disconnected
10-17 04:12:43.864 I/ActivityManager(   60): Start proc Test.Droid for activity Test.Droid/Test.droid.SplashScreenActivity: pid=632 uid=10045 gids={3003, 1015}
10-17 04:12:44.224 I/WindowManager(   60): Setting rotation to 1, animFlags=1
10-17 04:12:44.224 I/ActivityManager(   60): Config changed: { scale=1.0 imsi=310/260 loc=en_US touch=3 keys=1/1/2 nav=3/1 orien=2 layout=35 uiMode=17 seq=16}
10-17 04:12:44.564 I/ActivityThread(  632): Publishing provider Test.Droid.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.**mono_init**: mono.MonoRuntimeProvider
10-17 04:12:44.584 D/dalvikvm(  632): Trying to load lib /data/data/Test.Droid/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x44f51e18
10-17 04:12:44.584 D/dalvikvm(  632): Added shared lib /data/data/Test.Droid/lib/libmonodroid.so 0x44f51e18
10-17 04:12:44.834 W/MonoDroid-Debugger(  632): Trying to initialize the debugger with options: --debugger-agent=transport=dt_socket,loglevel=0,address=127.0.0.1:8909,server=y,embedding=1
10-17 04:12:44.884 W/MonoDroid-Debugger(  632): Accepted stdout connection: 29
10-17 04:12:45.724 E/mono    (  632): WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
10-17 04:12:45.724 E/mono    (  632): Using default runtime: v2.0.50727
10-17 04:12:48.644 W/monodroid-gc(  632): GREF GC Threshold: 1800
10-17 04:12:49.300 W/WindowManager(   60): App freeze timeout expired.
10-17 04:12:49.300 W/WindowManager(   60): Force clearing freeze: AppWindowToken{4514e258 token=HistoryRecord{450ac4f8 Test.Droid/Test.droid.SplashScreenActivity}}
10-17 04:12:51.495 D/dalvikvm(   60): GC_EXPLICIT freed 4408 objects / 254344 bytes in 129ms
10-17 04:12:53.635 W/ActivityManager(   60): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
10-17 04:12:54.454 W/ActivityManager(   60): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{450ac4f8 Test.Droid/Test.droid.SplashScreenActivity}
10-17 04:12:55.875 I/ActivityManager(   60): Displayed activity Test.Droid/Test.droid.SplashScreenActivity: 12050 ms (total 448199 ms)
10-17 04:12:57.884 I/mvx     (  632):   3.23 Setup: Conventions start
10-17 04:12:58.404 I/mono-stdout(  632): mvx:Diagnostic:  3.23 Setup: Conventions start
10-17 04:12:58.504 I/mvx     (  632):   4.08 Setup: App start
10-17 04:12:58.504 I/mono-stdout(  632): mvx:Diagnostic:  4.08 Setup: App start
10-17 04:12:58.544 I/mvx     (  632):   4.13 Setup: ViewsContainer start
10-17 04:12:58.544 I/mono-stdout(  632): mvx:Diagnostic:  4.13 Setup: ViewsContainer start
10-17 04:12:58.576 I/mvx     (  632):   4.16 Setup: ViewDispatcherProvider start
10-17 04:12:58.576 I/mono-stdout(  632): mvx:Diagnostic:  4.16 Setup: ViewDispatcherProvider start
10-17 04:12:58.604 I/mvx     (  632):   4.18 Setup: Views start
10-17 04:12:58.604 I/mono-stdout(  632): mvx:Diagnostic:  4.18 Setup: Views start
10-17 04:12:58.834 I/mvx     (  632):   4.42 Setup: LastChance start
10-17 04:12:58.834 I/mono-stdout(  632): mvx:Diagnostic:  4.42 Setup: LastChance start
10-17 04:12:58.924 I/mvx     (  632):   4.50 Setup: Secondary end
10-17 04:12:58.924 I/mono-stdout(  632): mvx:Diagnostic:  4.50 Setup: Secondary end
10-17 04:12:58.954 I/Navigation(  632):   4.53 Navigate to OfficeViewModel with args
10-17 04:12:58.954 I/mono-stdout(  632): Navigation:Diagnostic:  4.53 Navigate to OfficeViewModel with args
10-17 04:13:01.354 I/ActivityManager(   60): Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=Test.Droid/Test.droid.views.OfficeView (has extras) }
10-17 04:13:11.365 W/ActivityManager(   60): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
10-17 04:13:11.454 W/ActivityManager(   60): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{450c5c18 Test.Droid/Test.droid.views.OfficeView}
10-17 04:13:16.695 D/dalvikvm(  314): GC_EXPLICIT freed 152 objects / 7136 bytes in 170ms
10-17 04:13:21.494 W/ActivityManager(   60): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{450ac4f8 Test.Droid/Test.droid.SplashScreenActivity}
10-17 04:13:21.754 D/dalvikvm(  333): GC_EXPLICIT freed 162 objects / 7144 bytes in 148ms
10-17 04:13:26.744 D/dalvikvm(  299): GC_EXPLICIT freed 176 objects / 9128 bytes in 148ms

Comment: can you post the output of that debug log? Somewhere something will be tracing the problem

Comment: Hi Stuart, sorry for the delay but I started modifying your Tutorial project and incorporated my code into it which is working fine.I can post a sample project to you if you like

Comment: Your call :) Reading through that trace it just looks like your OfficeView isn't starting - which suggests a problem somewhere in the ViewModel or the View. If you have working code in the Tutorial, but not in your sample, then a windiff might tell you what it is...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I test any github samples in https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross a reply the same error.

In a other hand, I test a monodroid app, without use this framework and don't have this loop error.

I use a 2.2 android too.
I try the same project in android 4.0 and looping persist.